# Agreement Measure

Tags: pca, agreement-statistics

### The Situation

We have a set of audio transformations each described by their position in an 80 dimensional feature space, each dimension
corresponding to a particular feature of the transformation or the audio signals being transformed. Each of these transforms
is also labelled with a semantic descriptor (such as ‘warm’, ‘crunch’ or ‘fuzz’). Some sample data is shown here:

[image: Two dimensions of the feature space.]

What we want to measure is the level to which these semantic descriptors are agreed upon across the set of transforms
they label. Intuitively, if all the transforms labelled with are particular descriptor are group together in some meaningful
way, in the features space, that descriptor should receive a high agreement score. If the transforms labelled by a particular
descriptor are distributed across the entire feature space, the descriptor should receive a low agreement score.

A common approach to this is to sum the variances, in each dimension, for all of the transforms with a particular descriptor.
The agreement for a descriptor, d, is then given by:

$$A(d) = \frac{\log(N_{d})}{\sum_{k=1}^{K} \sigma_{d,k}^{2}}$$

Where $N_{d}$ is the total number of transforms labelled with descriptor $d$, $K$ is the total number of features
(dimensions in the features space) and $\sigma_{d,k}^{2}$ is the variance, in feature $k$, for transforms labelled with
descriptor $d$.

I don’t think this is a particularly good measure for a variety of reasons:

- The scaling by the log of the number of transforms doesn’t seem very rigorous to me. Clearly the agreement score
  should increase if there are more transforms within the same region of the space, but this method doesn’t seem
  statistically sound.
- It assumes that high variance, in any dimension, is a bad thing and should reduce the agreement score for a descriptor.
  It may be the case that a particular feature has no influence on the labelling of a transform and as such that feature
  should have little influence on the agreement score.
- It assumes that low variance is a good thing and should increase the agreement score. It may be the case that the
  value of a particular feature is the same for every transform, regardless of the descriptor used to label them. In this
  cast low variance should not influence the agreement score.
- It assumes that all features are independent. Summing the variances of each feature individually does not take into
  account the relationships between features.

Below are my thoughts on how we can improve on this measure.

### Variance vs Margin of Error

Firstly I think we should be using something a little more descriptive than just the raw variance of each feature. The margin
of error seems more appropriate to me. This would properly take into account the number of transforms and the expected
distribution of feature values.

### Sum of Reciprocals

Secondly, I think taking the reciprocal of the sum of variances measures the wrong thing. In the previous equation a high variance in
any feature will reduce the agreement score, regardless of how many features exhibit a low variance. Summing the individual
reciprocals of the margin of error in each feature makes more sense to me.

$$A(d) = \sum_{k=1}^{K} \frac{1}{E_{d,k}}$$

Where $E_{d,k}$ is the margin of error, in feature $k$, for transforms labelled with descriptor $d$.

In this way features with a large margin of error have little effect on the overall agreement score, while features with a small
margin or error will increase it.

### Using Principal Components

This still suffers from the problem of assuming a small margin of error is due to an agreement
between labels. We need to discard any features which have a small variance regardless of their descriptor. This can be done
using principal component analysis (PCA) on the entire feature space (including all transforms), and keeping only the first
$P$ principal components (PCs). If the transforms labelled with a particular descriptor exhibit low variance in one of these
first $P$ PCs it is likely that it is well agreed upon.

The problem now is that the PCs all describe different proportions of the variance in the original data.  This can be taken
into consideration by weighting the margin of error in each PC by the proportion of variance described by that PC. In a PC
which describes a large proportion of variance, a low variance is not expected and as such should be given a higher
weighting in the agreement score. In a PC which describes a low proportion of variance, a low variance is expected so the
weighting should be less. This gives rise to this equation:

$$A(d) = \sum_{p=1}^{P} \frac{V_{p}}{E_{d,p}}$$

Where $V_{p}$ is the proportion of variance described by PC $p$ and $E_{d,p}$ is the margin of error, in PC $p$, for
transforms labelled with descriptor $d$.

### Relationships Between PCs

One problem still remains that a certain descriptor might exhibit some relationship between two PCs. The original PCA is
performed on the entire feature space so only features which are proportional for all transforms will be combined into
single PCs. It is possible that two features are only related for transforms with a particular descriptor, in which case
they will most likely be split into two separate PCs. This means that, for some descriptors, there may be relationships that
exist between PCs which we need to capture in our agreement score.

My idea for this is to find the covariance matrix for transforms labelled with a particular descriptor in the first $P$ PCs,
then use its eigenvalues and eigenvectors in the calculation of the agreement score. Something like this:

$$A(d) = \sum_{i=1}^{P} \frac{V \cdot v_{d,i}}{\lambda_{d,i}}$$

Where $V$ is a vector containing the proportions of variances described by the first $P$ PCs, $v_{i}$ is the
$i^{\textrm{th}}$ eigenvector of the covariance matrix for transforms labelled with descriptor $d$ and $\lambda_{d,i}$ is
the corresponding eigenvalue.

The numerator here is the equivalent of weighting by the PC's proportions of variances as done previously. Taking the dot product of the eigenvector and a vector containing the PC's proportions of variance takes
into account the weighted variance described by the PCs to which the eigenvector is not orthogonal.

The use of eigenvalues could probably be improved by using a margin of error equivalent, but I'm not sure on what
distribution one would use in the calculation of such error measures.

### Questions

So, that is what I have thought about and here are some questions I have about it.

1. Does any of what I have said make any sense whatsoever?
2. Are there any existing statistical measures for this type of thing? I have looked at various inter rater reliability measures but none of them seem to apply.
3. What are your thoughts on the whole eigenvector weighting thing? It seems to make sense to me but maybe there are some gaping holes in my reasoning.
4. Any other suggestions you may have.

Thanks!